# Excel is plotting my date x-axis completely, and I cannot work out why

Tags: excel, charts, excel-charts

I have a very simple Excel data set which plots 15-minute date/time segments against values.

When I try to plot it as a line graph in Excel (mac), Excel inexplicably renders the results wrongly. It seems to plot only one value for each day, and I cannot determine how it is picking which value to show.

The only way I can get it plotted correctly is by changing the data into a Pivot table and then it plots fine, even though the data is exactly the same.

[You can see some sample data here with the Excel rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJTr2.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. While interesting, this question doesn't seem to be about programming. It may be better suited for https://superuser.com/.

Comment: What line chart did you pick? I find xy scatter works well.